# Dimension of a distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I have a distribution that can be written as follows:

$$
q(w, \lambda, \phi) = q(w) \times q(\lambda) \times q(\phi)
$$

Here the $q$'s denote densities. $q(w)$ is a multivariate normal distribution of n-dimensions and $q(\lambda)$ and $q(\phi)$ are univariate normal distributions. So, the joint distribution (coming from the assumption that these quantities are independent) can be written as $q(w, \lambda, \phi)$. Is the resulting distribution a $N + 2$ dimensional distribution? Can it be written as a multivariate distribution of dimension $N + 2$?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking that's an N+2 dimensional distribution. What are the $q$'s - are they densities? What do you mean by 'single multivariate distribution of dimension N+2? Haven't already specified one in your question?

Comment: @Glen_b I don't follow: when I multiply an $N$-vector by two scalars I get an $N$-vector.  In what sense do you call that an $N+2$-dimensional distribution?

Comment: @whuber The variables are not being multiplied, but the $q$'s, whatever they are. I took $q$ to denote a density, and the equation to indicate independence of each of the additional two variables ($\lambda$, $\phi$ -- but was careful to also ask about $q$ so I could confirm that) with $w$ (and each other). That is, an N+2 dimensional problem.

Comment: @Glen_b OK, I see, thank you.  I think this question is ambiguous, then: it is unclear whether $q$ is a density, a CDF, perhaps a random variable, or none of the above. It's also not entirely evident what is meant by "N+2 dimensional." (Perhaps that means having N+2 parameters?) Please help us out with this, Luca.

Comment: Sorry, it was ambiguous and largely due to my own ignorance. $q$s are densities. So, if I assume $q(w)$ is a multivariate normal distribution describing the density of a n-dimensional variable $w$ and $q(\lambda)$ and $q(\phi)$ are univariate normal densities. Can I say that the distribution $q(w, \lambda, \phi)$ is going to be a multivariate normal in $N+2$ dimensions?

Comment: Also, yes, I meant $N+2$ parameters. But more importantly, is the resulting distribution also a multivariate normal distribution with $N+2$ parameters?

Comment: Luca, there are two situations. As you have written the equation, the product of densities implies independence of the three components - and yes, that's multivariate normal. But if you just mean "I have three variables that are marginally normal, is their joint distribution normal" then the answer is no. Can you clarify that the product was intended to convey independence?

Comment: Ah yes, that is a tricky and subtle concept. Thanks for pointing it out. In my case, they are independent (assumed due to mean field approximation).